# What is the 'charmap' codec displayed in python's UnicodeErrors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, decode, encode

Running some simple code to see what encodings can decode a particular file as in:

```
encodings = ('cp737', 'cp869', 'cp875', 'cp1253', 'iso2022_jp_2', 'iso8859_7',
             'mac_greek', 'utf-8')

def test_encoding():
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        for c in csvs:
            for encoding in encodings:
                try:
                    with open(c, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
                        content = f.read()
                except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                    print(encoding, e) # <---- print from here
                    continue
                csv_out = os.path.join(tmp_dir, os.path.basename(
                    c[:-4]) + '_%s.csv' % encoding)
                with open(csv_out, 'w', encoding=encoding,
                          newline='\n') as f:
                    f.write(content)
        input('Files created in %s' % tmp_dir)
```

This prints:

```
cp869 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 28: character maps to <undefined>
cp1253 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 26: character maps to <undefined>
iso2022_jp_2 'iso2022_jp_2' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 18: illegal multibyte sequence
iso8859_7 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 84: character maps to <undefined>
```

So what is `'charmap' codec` ? Why sometimes it prints `'charmap' codec can't...` while in others as in `iso2022_jp_2` it prints the name of the encoding ?

I am on

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Comment: Could it be because some encodings are 1-on-1 mappings (normal one-byte encodings) and others are multi-byte? (Or maybe not. A counterexample: iso8859_7)

Comment: Yep thought so - but counterexample - so what is this charmap codec ? Try searching you will just encounter the millions `'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xXX in position YY`

Comment: Well iso8859_7 is also one byte @usr2564301 - then charmap stands for the one byte codecs ? Anyway - wouldn't it be more helpful if python printed the name of the codec in those errors ?

Comment: Check what the Python source code does for that specific line. (It's inside `exceptions.c`)

Comment: [Here ?](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c) - can't find charmap in there, they use some kind of reflection technique. I anyway wonder why not printing the name of the encoding `cp869 codec can't decode byte...` instead of `'charmap' codec can't decode byte...`. Is there any documentation on that 'charmap' codec ?

Comment: [Maybe here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/search.html?q=charmap) (the last found link, paragraph  _Encodings and Unicode_): _There’s another group of encodings (the so called **charmap encodings**) that …_.

Comment: ..going on to say `Each charmap encoding can decode any random byte sequence`, but see OP - anyway yes this is probably it @JosefZ